# MySql Time range count Query -

Tags: mysql

I need a validation query for when someone is booked a parking place in particular time another person should not book for that in between timings.....I have the below table:

And my query is

```
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM managebooking
    WHERE Time(BookingTimeFrom) AND Time(BookingTimeTo) 
                             BETWEEN '11:00' AND 02:00'
```

Please help me any one. Thanks!

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Badpw.png[image]

Comment: what you want ?

Comment: Your question is lacking a question.

Comment: You forgot to add question

Comment: i need a validation query for when someone is booked a parking place in particular time  another person should not book for that in between timings......

Comment: Update your question instead of adding comments

Comment: i have an answer to this SO. see below

Comment: Thank you so much. then this aspect is allowed. how to restrict ? SELECT count(*) FROM managebooking WHERE (Time(BookingTimeFrom) >= '11:00' AND Time(BookingTimeFrom) < '11:30' ) OR (Time(BookingTimeTo) > '11:00' AND Time(BookingTimeTo) <= '11:30' )

Comment: Middle fromtime and totime booking is allowed. How to restrict?

Comment: What are the types of the different columns of your table? All all the fields varchars or time and date?

Comment: Its mixed. Int, Varchar, Date and Time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below query will check if there is conflict of current booking time for a given day. We cannot use between because between is inclusive and we do allow adjacent bookings. For example; if there is an existing booking from 8-9am then we can allow another booking from 9 and onwards. Also, include seconds for accuracy. here is a demo_: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d09c9/63

```
  SELECT count(*)
FROM managebooking
WHERE (Time(BookingTimeFrom)   >= '08:35:00' 
AND Time(BookingTimeTo) > '08:35:00'
AND Time(BookingTimeFrom)  < '09:45:00')
OR (Time(BookingTimeFrom)  < '08:35:00' 
AND Time(BookingTimeTo)  > '08:35:00'
AND Time(BookingTimeFrom) < '09:45:00');
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  then this aspect is allowed. how to restrict ?          SELECT count(*)
FROM managebooking
WHERE (Time(BookingTimeFrom)  >= '11:00' 
     AND Time(BookingTimeFrom) <  '11:30' ) 
OR (Time(BookingTimeTo) > '11:00' 
     AND Time(BookingTimeTo) <=  '11:30' )

Comment: Middle time fromtime and totime booking is allowed. How to restrict?

Comment: fixing this. pls wait

Comment: Thank you. then its not working some aspect. see that please.     SELECT count(*)
FROM managebooking
WHERE Time(BookingTimeFrom) 
  <= '08:15:00' 
AND Time(BookingTimeTo) 
   > '08:15:00'
AND Time(BookingTimeFrom) 
   < '09:15:00'

Comment: How to fix it? Any idea? please tell me

Comment: this was harder than I thought. I test using 13 test cases and updated my answer. How many test cases do you have?

Comment: I have 10 test case. But your query is working horse power. Thanks lot. Its working very charming. Thanks for saving my time. Thank u soo much .